# ¿Cómo saber si un botón fue presionado con librerías Tkinter y Pillow en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, botón

Me encuentro haciendo un proyecto en Python y me surgió una duda.

Me encuentro trabajando con la librería **Tkinter** de Python y requiero que al momento de presionar un botón, este yendo a una función me muestre la imagen correspondiente utilizando la librería de imágenes **Pillow**. Pero con mi código no importa cual botón seleccione, me muestra solo la imagen de la ultima variable *CodigoImg*.

Mi pregunta, habrá algún comando o forma para saber *que botón fue seleccionado* y así mostrar la imagen correspondiente, sin necesidad de crear funciones diferentes para cada botón. ***¿?***

El siguiente es una parte de mi código donde se crean los botones:

```
picSubtema = Frame(root, 
               bg = "#F50909")
picSubtema.grid(row = 0, column = 4, pady = 10)

Sub = Label(picSubtema, text = ("PRODUCTO/DIVISION\nDE FRACCION") , 
                    fg="black", bg = "#E7E5E5", 
                    font=("Century Gothic",10))
Sub.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 10)

CodigoImg = "4.1"
ImgSub4_1 = Button(picSubtem, text = ("Explicación 1"), 
                    fg="black", bg = "#E7E5E5", 
                    font=("Century Gothic",10),
                    command = images)
ImgSub4_1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

CodigoImg = "4.2"
ImgSub4_2 = Button(picSubtema, text = ("Explicación 2"), 
                    fg="black", bg = "#E7E5E5", 
                    font=("Century Gothic",10),
                    command = images)
ImgSub4_2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
```

Código de la función para que aparezcan las imágenes:

```
def images():

global CodigoImg

    if CodigoImg == "4.1":
        imagen = Image.open("img/ProductoFraccion.png")
        imagen.show()
    elif CodigoImg == "4.2":
        imagen = Image.open("img/DivisionFraccion.png")
        imagen.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pongo un ejemplo funcional, solo adaptalo a tus necesidades:

```
#-*- coding: utf - 8 -*-

from tkinter import *

def images(boton):#boton sería el parámetro recibido
   if boton == 1:   
      print("botón uno") #acá mostrás la imagen
   if boton == 2:
      print("botón dos")
      


ventana = Tk()

ImgSub4_1 = Button(ventana, text = ("Explicación 1"),command = lambda:images(1)) #con lambda le pasamos un parámetro a la función
ImgSub4_1.pack()
ImgSub4_2 = Button(ventana, text = ("Explicación 2"),command = lambda:images(2))
ImgSub4_2.pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```